# Where to find .htaccess file in my Xampp localhost ubuntu linux

Tags: linux, apache, .htaccess, ubuntu

I have a simple problem here. I am a beginner in using php and apache. Actually, I want to modify some configuration in my localhost .htaccess, it is in ubuntu linux, but I can't find it. It is possible that it is hidden, how can I make it appear?

Comment: In a terminal: `ls -a`.

Comment: ls -a
.              Escritorio        .profile
..             examples.desktop  Público
.bash_history  .gconf            .sudo_as_admin_successful
.bash_logout   .gnome            teamviewer_amd64.deb
.bashrc        .gnupg            Vídeos
.cache         .ICEauthority     .wget-hsts
.compiz        Imágenes          www
.config        .local            .Xauthority
.dbus          .mozilla          .xsession-errors
Descargas      Música            .xsession-errors.old
.dmrc          .pki
Documentos     Plantillas